# How to Model Archimedean Snub Cube?

Tags: modeling, objects, object-mode

I need to create the [Snub Cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_cube) - 'right' and 'left' versions (It is a [chiral polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_polytope)). My blender knowledge is not very good.

Right:

[image]

Left:

[image]

Comment: There's an [STL file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Snub_cube.stl) on the Wikipedia page about it, you can import it into Blender.

Answer (score 2):

The Snub Cube as well as MANY other polyhedra are available from the Mesh Extra Objects Addon (a default Blender Addon).

Install it from Edit / Preferences - Addons

Search for: Extra Objects

Pick: Add Mesh: Extra Objects (Click the Check Box to Enable it)

In Blender's View Screen, use Shift-A / Mesh and scroll down to "Math Function"

Open Math Function and click on "Regular Solid"

In the "Presets" drop down select "Snub Cube" then left or right from the options.

Comment: Here's a video.  What I'm talking about is about seven minutes, 30 seconds in: https://youtu.be/br_dwbZe2P0?t=446